# Align 3 buttons on same row with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu, alignment

For the three orange buttons titled "Action" below, I am trying to display them inline, horizontally, on the same line (evenly distributed across the row). I put them in a "btn-group", which I thought automatically handled this.

[image]

Do I need to use col sizes to add up to twelve? How can I evenly distribute the three buttons on the same line?

The three buttons within the "btn-group" are can be found at the bottom of my code. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="c-form-container section-container section-container-image-bg">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 c-form section-description wow fadeIn">
        <h1>Happy <strong>Hour</strong></h1>
        <p>If you win, you drink for free, and your friends half off!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 c-form-box wow fadeInUp">

        <div class="c-form-top">
          <div class="c-form-top-left">
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            <p>Fill in the form below to win a happy hour:</p>
          </div>
          <div class="c-form-top-right">
            <div class="c-form-top-right-icon">
              <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="c-form-bottom">
          <form role="form" action="assets/contact.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="c-form-name">
                <span class="label-text">Name:</span>
                <span class="contact-error"></span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" class="c-form-name form-control" id="c-form-name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="c-form-birthday">
                <span class="label-text">Birthday:</span>
                <span class="contact-error"></span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Your Birthday" class="c-form-birthday form-control" id="c-form-birthday">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="c-form-email">
                <span class="label-text">Email:</span>
                <span class="contact-error"></span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="c-form-email form-control" id="c-form-email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="c-form-cell">
                <span class="label-text">Cell Phone:</span>
                <span class="contact-error"></span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="cell" placeholder="Your Cell Phone Number" class="c-form-cell form-control" id="c-form-cell">
            </div>


            <div class="btn-group">

              <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit Information</button>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css file:

```css
body {

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

  font-size: 16px;

  font-weight: 300;

  color: #888;

  line-height: 30px;

  text-align: center;

}

strong {

  font-weight: 500;

}

a,

a:hover,

a:focus {

  color: #de615e;

  text-decoration: none;

  -o-transition: all .3s;

  -moz-transition: all .3s;

  -webkit-transition: all .3s;

  -ms-transition: all .3s;

  transition: all .3s;

}

h1,

h2 {

  margin-top: 10px;

  font-size: 38px;

  font-weight: 100;

  color: #555;

  line-height: 50px;

}

h3 {

  font-size: 22px;

  font-weight: 300;

  color: #555;

  line-height: 30px;

}

img {

  max-width: 100%;

}

::-moz-selection {

  background: #de615e;

  color: #fff;

  text-shadow: none;

}

::selection {

  background: #de615e;

  color: #fff;

  text-shadow: none;

}

.btn-link-1 {

  display: inline-block;

  height: 50px;

  margin: 5px;

  padding: 16px 20px 0 20px;

  background: #de615e;

  font-size: 16px;

  font-weight: 300;

  line-height: 16px;

  color: #fff;

  -moz-border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

  border-radius: 4px;

}

.btn-link-1:hover,

.btn-link-1:focus,

.btn-link-1:active {

  outline: 0;

  opacity: 0.6;

  color: #fff;

}

.btn-link-1.btn-link-1-facebook {

  background: #4862a3;

}

.btn-link-1.btn-link-1-twitter {

  background: #55acee;

}

.btn-link-1.btn-link-1-google-plus {

  background: #dd4b39;

}

.btn-link-1 i {

  padding-right: 5px;

  vertical-align: middle;

  font-size: 20px;

  line-height: 20px;

}

.btn-link-2 {

  display: inline-block;

  height: 50px;

  margin: 5px;

  padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  border: 1px solid #fff;

  font-size: 16px;

  font-weight: 300;

  line-height: 16px;

  color: #fff;

  -moz-border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

  border-radius: 4px;

}

.btn-link-2:hover,

.btn-link-2:focus,

.btn-link-2:active,

.btn-link-2:active:focus {

  outline: 0;

  opacity: 0.6;

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  color: #fff;

}

/***** Top content *****/

.inner-bg {

  padding: 100px 0 170px 0;

}

.top-content .text {

  color: #fff;

}

.top-content .text h1 {

  color: #fff;

}

.top-content .description {

  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;

}

.top-content .description p {

  opacity: 0.8;

}

.top-content .description a {

  color: #fff;

}

.top-content .description a:hover,

.top-content .description a:focus {

  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;

}

.form-box {

  margin-top: 35px;

}

.form-top {

  overflow: hidden;

  padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;

  background: #444;

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);

  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;

  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;

  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;

  text-align: left;

}

.form-top-left {

  float: left;

  width: 75%;

  padding-top: 25px;

}

.form-top-left h3 {

  margin-top: 0;

  color: #fff;

}

.form-top-left p {

  opacity: 0.8;

  color: #fff;

}

.form-top-right {

  float: left;

  width: 25%;

  padding-top: 5px;

  font-size: 66px;

  color: #fff;

  line-height: 100px;

  text-align: right;

  opacity: 0.3;

}

.form-bottom {

  padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;

  background: #444;

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;

  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;

  text-align: left;

}

.form-bottom form textarea {

  height: 100px;

}

.form-bottom form button.btn {

  width: 100%;

}

.form-bottom form .input-error {

  border-color: #de615e;

}

.social-login {

  margin-top: 35px;

}

.social-login h3 {

  color: #fff;

}

.social-login-buttons {

  margin-top: 25px;

}

/***** Media queries *****/

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .inner-bg {

    padding:60px 0 110px 0;

  }

}

@media (max-width: 415px) {

  h1,

  h2 {

    font-size: 32px;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
 <div class='btn-toolbar'>
    <div class='btn-group'>
        <button class="btn-danger signin">Sign In</button>
        <button class="btn-success signup">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding 'btn-toolbar', no effect. Thanks though

Comment: are you using any other css file that's affecting it?

Comment: I guess my problem is I don't know which CSS element is hindering my btn-group.....

Answer (score 1):

i have run your code and its  look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E3Ky.jpg)

so your code is right maybe you done some changes in css pass. 
Check it using inspect element near action button look how much width you have given in style part

Comment: My css uses an "align vertical: middle" i want that for the text inputs, but how could I make an exception for the buttons so they would horizontally align?

Comment: check your css file or is there any stylesheet ?

Comment: stylesheet is posted

Comment: do it with yourself by inspect elements that would help you in debugging code and you get to know how to make changes in any template.